# Is it possibel to get that “Padlock” symbol in the address bar for a localhost https connection that uses a self signed certificate?

Tags: ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate, https, security

I am currently implemented SSL for my Web App in tomcat using a self signed certificate using java Keystore tool.

I am using the web app in my machine as localhost. When I visit the url

```
https://localhost:8443
```

The padlock symbol does not appear in the address bar but the page loads successfully.

Why this happening ?

Does openSSl resolve this issue ?

Comment: Which browsers have you tried? What's your OS?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf  Windows in Mozilla Firefox

Answer (score 2):

In order for the browser to declare the site as secure it would need to trust the certificate and it won't trust a self signed certificate. Create a CA and import it into the your tomcats trust store . use the CA to sign a new certificate which you can import into tomcats key store,  then import the CA into your browser trust store. The browser should now trust the certificate. Some browsers/ servers may insist on a verification depth of more than 1 in which case you will need to also create an intermediate CA such that the first CA signs the Intermediate CA signs the certificate.